# Change polyline points

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to change polyline after placing it on  map, but it's point list appears to be unchangable. CRUD operations on points list of polyline not working.

```
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()   //New PolylineOptions
    .add(new LatLng(FromNode.Lat, FromNode.Lon))          //with 2 coordinates
    .add(new LatLng(ToNode.Lat, ToNode.Lon));
Polyline polyPath = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);     //Add polyline on map
polyPath.getPoints().remove(0);                           //Should remove 0 element
polyPath.getPoints().size();                              //Still 2 elements
polyPath.getPoints().add(new LatLng(0,0));                //Add new point
polyPath.getPoints().size();                              //Still 2 elements
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Polyline.getPoints();
```

Creates a copy of points list, it's not a reference to actual list of points.
To set new list of points, need to get initial points list, change it and set it to polyline.

```
List<LatLng> pointsList = Polyline.getPoints();
pointsList.remove(1);
pointsList.set(0, new LatLng(1,1));
pointsList.add(new LatLng(0,0));
Polyline.setPoints(pointsList);
```